How to link to source code in junit error stacktrace
How would we go about adding links back to our source code in junit XML report stack traces? The link would be back to the web app for our source code repository (e.g., github, gitlab, bitbucket, etc.).
We currently have junit XML reports that include the stack trace for failed tests, and we've seen other tools (e.g., SpecFlow .NET tests) that are able to include the links back to the source code (for our code only).
We've searched around for packages that would help to do such a thing, but we're not yet having success in finding a viable option.

Show an example of what you have and how do you want to change it
